# unexpected keyword Const : Const keyword is not allowded in the strict mode in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

[image]I am new to the `react-native.` I am trying to run a simple app .But It is giving me lots of problems, which are related to the dependencies.

what I have is ,

I have set my babel to

```
{

}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactCourse",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I am not understanding why is this giving me this error .

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: in which line and where you got error ?

Comment: I actually I have just set up the project without using the expo

Comment: I have added an image which has the error

Comment: And one more thing, In my editor now props are getting a underline with red means it is not recognizing that

Comment: try after setting babel `{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}`

Comment: I have gone through the git hub , but this solution has downvotes.